# Unveil.js not working in div

Tags: jquery

I was using `Unveil.js` to do the lazy load for my web application. Normally use everything is fine, but when I custom the div to a scrollable div then `Unveil.js` doesn't work anymore. Any suggestion to do lazy loading inside a scrollable div ?

`scollable div code`

```
.myscrollablediv{
    height:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.myscrollablediv::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 4px;

}
.myscrollablediv::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color:#ccc;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    opacity:0.5;
    position:absolute;
}
.myscrollablediv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #5d5d5d;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Code please? Not sure what is meant by 'I custom the div to a scrollable div'

Comment: @BenRondeau just added the code

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom the div'?

Comment: @benrondeau customize it by making it scrollable?

Comment: @BenRondeau make it to scrollable

Comment: @BenRondeau yup, so the window are actually not moving/scroll only my `myscrollablediv` able to scroll and the `unveil` element is inside this `myscrollablediv`

Answer (score 4):

Use [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). No JS configuration is needed. After including the lazysizes script, add the class `lazyload` to your images and switch `src` to `data-src`. That's it.

Comment: We've used unveil.js on our site for a couple years without any issues.  Switched over to lazysizes on your recommendation.  It's just better.

Answer (score 1):

Unveil.js relies on the browser window to evaluate when to load images. Checkout the [source code](https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil/blob/master/jquery.unveil.js) and see where the variable `$w` is defined and used. Line 48 is the listening event for the Unveil property to work which in turn is waiting for the window to move.

Since you are placing an element (a div in this case) inside a scrollable element, the window is not moving (only the content inside the div is) and therefore Unveil.js does not know to reveal images (since it only listens to window movement).

This library will not work for your needs as is. It is possible that you could adapt this library to listen to your div instead of the window object and what is currently viewable in the viewport, but that sounds like a huge headache to create and will likely have a ton of weird bugs browser to browser.

Unless there is a TON of content in this scrollable div, just load it all at once and avoid lazy loading.